# Exception when adding more than one entity at once

Tags: entity-framework, wcf-ria-services

Whenever I do something like the following:

```
public class MyDto
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public int ParentID { get; set; }

    public String Name { get; set; }
}

MyDataContext dataContext = new MyDataContext();

MyParentDto myParentDto; // <-- Existing parent DTO querried from the server. Has a relation to MyDto on MyDto.ParentID == MyParentDto.ID.
List<MyDto> myDtos = new List<MyDto>();

myDtos.Add(new MyDto
    {
        Name = "First MyDto!"
    });

myDtos.Add(new MyDto
    {
        Name = "Second MyDto!"
    });

// Some time later.


foreach (var myDto in myDtos)
{
    myDto.ParentID = myParentDto.ID;
    dataContext.MyDtos.Add(myDto);
}

dataContext.SubmitChanges(OnMyCallback)
```

I get the following vague exception, but my data submits just fine:

```
System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.DomainOperationException: Submit operation failed.  An entity with the same identity already exists in this EntitySet.
```

The stack trace ends with:

```
System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.EntitySet.AddToCache(Entity entity)
System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.Entity.AcceptChanges()
```

Both `MyDto` instances are set to `Detached` before they are added to `dataContext` and `New` afterwards.  If I reduce the number of added `MyDto` instances to one, I get no error.  If I call `SubmitChanges` in between the two adds.  Again, both of the `MyDto` instances are added to the database just fine, but the client crashes with the Exception.  What is going on?  Thanks.

**Edits:**

```
// On the server

[Insert]
public void InsertMyDto(MyDto a_myDto) // <- Yes I prefix. :p
{
    try
    {
        MyEntity myEntity = new MyDto
        {
            ParentID = a_myDto.ParentID,
            Name = a_myDto.Name
        }   

        ObjectContext.MyEntities.AddObject(myEntity);
        ObjectContext.SaveChanges();

    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw; // <- Never hits this spot.
    }
}

// Call back

public void OnMyCallback(SubmitOperation a_submitOperation)
{
        if (a_submitOperation.HasError)
            throw a_submitOperation.Error; // <- It doesn't matter if I have this or not, the client crashes anyway.

        // Other stuff that is not hit because it throws the exception above.
}
```

Comment: Is `ID` an auto-increment column? And if so, does EF know that?

Comment: can you post your submit changes code? (plus the callback action)

Comment: @Jordan For your second "yes", how does EF know that? I don't see it in your question.

Comment: @hvd, Through the `MyEntity` data entity. The `ID` field of `MyEntity` is set to be `Identity`store generated pattern and `Entity Key` is true. I added the server code above.

Comment: @sebastian, Added server and callback code above. Thanks.

Comment: Is MyDTO related to other entities, maybe part of a Composition?

Comment: @sebastian, as said above in the comments of the code, `MyDto` has a one-to-many relationship with `MyParentDto` on `MyDto.ParentID == MyParentDto.ID`.  This relationship is established both in the database and with the Entity Framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that the solution to my problem is to save the ID back to the dto when the entity is saved. Like this:

```
[Insert]
public void InsertMyDto(MyDto a_myDto) // <- Yes I prefix. :p
{
    try
    {
        MyEntity myEntity = new MyDto
        {
            ParentID = a_myDto.ParentID,
            Name = a_myDto.Name
        }   

        ObjectContext.MyEntities.AddObject(myEntity);
        ObjectContext.SaveChanges();

        a_myDto.ID = myEntity.ID; // <- Solution

    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw; // <- Never hits this spot.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting the parent instead of it's ID?

```
foreach (var myDto in myDtos)
{
    myDto.Parent = myParentDto;
} //Assuming myParentDto is already in the context, if not add it first
```

**Edit**: I'm taking a wild guess here but could you check the `HashCode` of the objects right before the Exception occurs? You could also try overriding the `GetHashCode()` method to return something random every time just to test those are the exact entities involved in the exception.

Comment: Yeah, I considered this, but I don't believe the parent relationship is the problem.  I'll try it though.  The trouble seems to be when it comes back and tries to cache the DTO's; consider the stack trace.